# Add Axes to D3 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, d3.js, svg

There is a graph that was drawn using *d3 canvas*.

```
var canvas = d3.select('#canvas_row').append('canvas')
                 .attr({'width': canvas_width, 'height': canvas_height})
                 .style({'width': graph_width + 'px', 'height': graph_height + 'px'});
context = canvas.node().getContext('2d');
image = context.createImageData(dx, dy);
```

And now I want to add axes to it. I tried to do that using *svg* like here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3074470 but I need to use *canvas* variable several times. And in this case an error `canvas.node(...).getContext is not a function` occurs.

Are there any other ways to add axes to d3 canvas?

Thanks!

Comment: Check by console logging `canvas.node()` just before the breaking line of code and ensure it is the canvas element. `console.log(canvas.node());`

Comment: It's svg element. But how to convert svg element to html?

Comment: SVG element itself is an html5 element. No need for any conversion. The problem here is, the `getContext()` method is supported for html5 canvas elements and not to the SVG elements.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: this shows how http://bl.ocks.org/tommct/8047063